# How to resize emoji image using scalerel

Tags: latex, emoji

I want to insert emojis in latex table and for this I have followed all steps as done in http://www.thetawelle.de/?p=5539

But the size of emoji is very small. I need help as to how to increase size of emoji in the table.

```
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\emojif60d{\scalerel*{\includegraphics{f60d.pdf}}{O}}
```

In the the table I have used: `\emojif60d`.

Comment: you might get more answers to this question at https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You do not need scalerel. It is mostly useful for scaling text, math, etc.

There is all that is required in the \includegraphics macro.

- either scale=<scale_factor>
- or width=<desired_width> (or height=<desired_height>)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{1F600}&
  \includegraphics[scale=1]{1F600}&
  \includegraphics[scale=2]{1F600}&
  \includegraphics[scale=4]{1F600}&
  \includegraphics[scale=8]{1F600}\\\hline
  \includegraphics[width=0.25cm]{1F600}&
  \includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{1F600}&
  \includegraphics[width=1cm]{1F600}&
  \includegraphics[width=2cm]{1F600}&
  \includegraphics[width=8cm]{1F600}\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To scale all occurrences of the emoji, you could include the scale in the definition, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\def\emojif60d{\includegraphics[width=2em]{1F60D.pdf}}

\begin{document}


\emojif60d

\end{document}
```

If it should only be scaled sometimes, you could use `\scalebox` from the `graphicx` package or use a bigger font size, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\def\emojif60d{\scalerel*{\includegraphics{1F60D.pdf}}{O}}

\begin{document}


\scalebox{3}{\emojif60d}

\emojif60d


\Huge\emojif60d

\end{document}
```

The latter approach will have the advantage that you will still be able to use the emoji inside of normal text and the size will be adapted to the font size.